# Create simple website with left menu and right content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I hope to create a website simple website with:

1. Left menu with items to click
2. When each item clicked, right menu is changed with new content. The content is always: title, picture 1, text description, picture 2. Same format for all left menu items.

Ideally I want the page to be just 1 page, without frame or separate .html files. If the item is clicked, jQuery will change the photos on right side with photo url in some array.

Is there an easy way to create this with existing templates somewhere? Either from internet, Wordpress (without database), Dreamweaver, or Dreamweaver plug-in... I just want to avoid having to do from scratch.

If you imagine this right, it could be just like a help page from MSDN, IBM or Apple Developer website. Just don't want to do each html separately due to potential change in format later.

Thanks.

Comment: @HP , whatever you want can be achieved very easily with divs or tables , there is no need to use any tools or so , you can just do it with jquery and html and css...

Comment: @HP start writing the code and let the comunity know if get stuck somewhere,

Comment: did someone just recommend html tables for a dynamic layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, each "page" should be placed in a div that is hidden with css. jQuery can show and hide the divs with a variety of effects.

I have created a simple example for you here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RLdmZ/2/

Comment: +1 for you for creating a sample for the OP, nice work with patience

Comment: Maybe OK with a very simple site and I doubt that the result with a search engine is acceptable since a match maybe hidden to the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the exact specifications you require may not exist already, there are other options in jQuery.

Notably, a search for a 'jQuery gallery' returns many options varying in design, implementation and complexity.

Have a [look](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+gallery) for yourself!

I hope this answer solves your question.

It's my first answer, so go easy! :]